# SQL Server Authentication Error. 18456 State 5

Tags: sql-server, authentication, entity-framework-6

I'm having problems logging into our database using a newly created domain account 'X' specially made for a new application I'm developing. This account is a member of a group that is given access to the Server and Database. Other members in the group are not having authentication issues.

When I login to my workstation using account 'X', I can connect to SQL Server Management Studio through Windows Authentication. But if I use account 'X' in a connection string, SQL Server can't authenticate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state 5` suggests "Invalid userid"

Which leads to:

> Invalid userID: SQL Server is not able to find the specified UserID on
>   the server you are trying to get. The most common cause is that this
>   userID hasn’t been granted access on the server but this could be also
>   a simple typo or you accidentally are trying to connect to different
>   server (Typical if you use more than one server)

Recheck the setting for your user account and also your authentication mode so you know the server will accept the connection for the specified user.

Comment: Thanks! I had to add the user as a new login acct on sql server.